# Append to last (or n-th) line of function (using awk/sed)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, sh

Preferably using awk, sed or similar, how can I implement `append_last_line`, eg. append something to the **last** line of the body of a function, which can be anywhere in a given file?

```sh
# file.sh
foo ()
{
  echo "bar"
}
```

`$ append_last_line 'foo' 'echo "baz"' file.sh`

```sh
# file.sh
foo ()
{
  echo "bar"
  echo "baz"
}
```

What about the **n-th** line?

```sh
# file.sh
foo ()
{
  echo "bar"
  echo "baz"
}
```

`$ append_nth_line 1 'foo' 'echo "qux"' file.sh`

```sh
# file.sh
foo ()
{
  echo "baz"
  echo "qux"
  echo "bar"
}
```

Comment: `What about the n-th line` of what? the function? the file? something else? Make sure your sample input/output covers all your requirements.

Comment: @eheu Simple solution (might not be enough for complex problems, i.e., you may need a real shell parser to identify where functions start): open input file, search for `^function ()`, search for `^\}`, write out everything until there except the `}` to a temp file, write your line, write `}`, copy everything until end of file to new file, close input file, rename temp file to new file.

Comment: @eheu for function's n-th line: search for `^{`, start counting lines (and checking you don't reach `^}` before n-th line), then write your line and the rest of the input file out.

Comment: @EdMorton I have edited my question to be more intelligible.

Comment: @rturrado That could work! Though, I wonder if somebody can think of a solution using some sed or awk code. Did you have vi in mind for implementing your solution?

Comment: @eheu Haha, I did! Vim macros. Although, for that pseudo code, I was thinking of bash commands. A `while read` loop, some pattern matching for the function name and the curly braces and a counter should suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously any script you write to do this will be fragile since you need a parser for the language that your target file is written in to do this job robustly but here's something that'll do what you want with the samples you provided:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

(( $# > 3 )) && { tgtLineNr=$1; shift; }
tgtFunc=$1
newText=$2
shift 2

awk -v tgtLineNr="$tgtLineNr" -v tgtFunc="$tgtFunc" -v newText="$newText" '

    state == "gotFuncBeg" {
        if ( /^}/ ) { state = "gotFuncEnd" }
        if ( (lineNr++ == tgtLineNr) || ((state == "gotFuncEnd") && !tgtLineNr) ) {
            sub(/[^[:space:]].*/,"",indent)
            print indent newText
        }
        if ( NF ) { indent = $0 }
    }

    (state == "gotFuncName") && /^{/ {
        state = "gotFuncBeg"
        lineNr = 0
    }

    /^[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*[[:space:]]*\(/ {
        thisFunc = $0
        sub(/[[:space:]]*\(.*/,"",thisFunc)
        state = (thisFunc == tgtFunc ? "gotFuncName" : "")
    }

    { print }
' "$@"
```

```
$ cat file
# file.sh
foo ()
{
  echo "bar"
  echo "baz"
}
```

```
$ ./tst.sh 'foo' 'echo "qux"' file
# file.sh
foo ()
{
  echo "bar"
  echo "baz"
  echo "qux"
}
```

```
$ ./tst.sh 1 'foo' 'echo "qux"' file
# file.sh
foo ()
{
  echo "bar"
  echo "qux"
  echo "baz"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something to get you started:

```
awk -v name=foo -v num=2 -v what='echo "qux"' '
   # Print the line and read next line and handle getline error
   function print_getline() {
        print;
        if (getline <= 0) exit 1;
   }
   $0 ~ name "[[:space:]]*()"{                     # match the function followed by ()
          while ($0 !~ "{") { print_getline(); }   # wait for {
          while (num--) { print_getline(); }       # omit num count lines
          print what;                              # add the line you want to add
   }
   { print }   # print all other lines
' <<EOF
# file.sh
foo ()
{
  echo "bar"
  echo "baz"
}
EOF
```

will output:

```
# file.sh
foo ()
{
  echo "bar"
echo "qux"
  echo "baz"
}
```

There are many good introductions to `awk` on the net. `awk` is a great language. If you however intent to write a full shell language parser to handle all corner cases (ie. `echo "foo () {"` is not a function definition...), consider using a more powerful language, like perl or python.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the awesome scripts, guys! I'll be sure to delve into them.

I ended up writing this script based on the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66216340/append-to-last-or-n-th-line-of-function-using-awk-sed#comment117067984_66216340) from @rturrado

```
$ cat append-nth-line.sh
#!/bin/bash
IFS=''

function_name=$1
nth=$2
append=$3
out=$4

declare function_start_line
declare function_end_line

search="on"
i=1

while read -r line; do
  echo $line >>tmp1
  if [[ $(echo $line | xargs) =~ ^($function_name[[:space:]]*?\(\)) ]]; then
    function_start_line=$i
  fi
  if [ $function_start_line ]; then
    if [[ $(echo $line | xargs) =~ ^} && $search = "on" ]]; then
      function_end_line=$i
      search="off"
    fi
  fi
  i=$(($i + 1))
done

if [[ "$nth" =~ ^- ]]; then
  find=$(($function_end_line + $nth))
else
  find=$(($function_start_line + $nth))
fi

i=1

cat tmp1 |
  while read -r line; do
    echo $line >>tmp2
    if [[ $i = $find ]]; then
      indent=$(echo $line | grep -o ^'[[:space:]]*')
      if [[ ! "$nth" =~ ^- && $(echo $line | xargs) =~ \{|then|else|do ]]; then
        indent="$indent  "
      fi
      echo "$indent$append" >>tmp2
    fi
    i=$(($i + 1))
  done

rm tmp1
chmod +x tmp2
mv tmp2 $out
```

```
$ cat file.sh
foo()
{
  echo "bar"
}
```

```
$ append_nth_line.sh "foo" -1 'echo "baz"' file.sh  < file.sh 
$ cat file.sh
foo()
{
  echo "bar"
  echo "baz"
}
```

```
$ append_nth_line.sh "foo" 1 'echo "qux"' file.sh  < file.sh 
$ cat file.sh
foo()
{
  echo "qux"
  echo "bar"
  echo "baz"
}
```

I still have some edge cases to work out, but this or your scripts will do.

Feedback welcomed.

Comment: Please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the reasons not to do that, copy/paste the script into http://shellcheck.net for other issues, and there are almost certainly more issues not covered by either of those. A shell is an environment from which to call tools (and manipulate files/processes) with a language to sequence those calls, it's not a tool to manipulate text. The guys who invented shell also invented awk for that task.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for sharing! I had no idea about this. Actually, I was so happy until now using `for` loops and `while read` loops in the command line and for little scripts. I definitely have to learn awk!

Comment: You're welcome. Another good read if you find yourself considering using `for` loops: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001.

Answer (score 0):

> … sed or similar

Using [ed](/questions/tagged/ed):

```
set -- filename funcname -1 '  echo "quux"'
printf '%s\n' '/^'"$2"'[ (]/;#' '/^}/;#' "$3"a "$4" . w q | ed -rs "$1"
```

which looks up `funcname`, then the trailing `}`, appends text at the
line before `}` (-1), and finally saves the edited file.

Call with -1 for last line, -3 for 3rd last ...

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):

```
# append_last_line 'foo' 'echo "baz"' file.sh
append_last_line (){ sed '/^'$1'\s*()/{:a;h;n;/^}$/!ba;x;s/\S.*/'"$2"'/p;x}' "$3"; }

# append_nth_line 2 'foo' 'echo "baz"' file.sh N.B. n must be natural number > 0
append_nth_line (){ sed -E '/^'$2'\s*\(\)/{n;n;:a;N;/^}/M!ba;s/(((\s*)[^\n]*(\n)){'$1'})/&\3'"$3"'\4/}' "$4"; }
```